# problem creating a simple relationship in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the database diagram to simply drag one column in a table to another to associate them and then trying to save it.  i have done this a million times in the past with no problems.  Both of the data types are the same, uniqueidentifier.

Here is the error I get:

> 'Customer ' table saved successfully
>   'CustomerOrder ' table
>   - Unable to create relationship 'FK_CustomerOrder_Customer'.
>   The
>   ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with
>   the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_CustomerOrder_Customer". The
>   conflict occurred in database
>   "mydatabase", table "Customer", column
>   'CustomerID'.

Not sure how to trouble shoot this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that there's a CustomerID in the CustomerOrder which can not be found in the Customer table.

Run this query inside SQL Server Management Studio separately:

```
SELECT *
FROM CustomerOrder co
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Customer c WHERE c.CustomerID = co.CustomerID)
```

and that should tell you what the "bad" Customer Order records are.

Answer (score 2):

Are there customer orders with customer id's that don't exist in the customer table?